# Take number from file with awk

Tags: awk

i am trying to take a number from a file that contains this :

```
     <span class="num text-emphasized">
      3,200
    </span>
    commits
```

I am using this function I wrote :

```
awk '
 BEGIN { found=0 }
/<span class="num text-emphasized">/ { found=1 }
found == 1 && /[:digit:]/ { print ; num=$0 }
found == 1 && /commits/ { exit 1 }
 END   { print num
}' myFile
```

I am trying to get the number 3,200 (or 3200 if possible). But I can't find it ...

This is the output I have :

```
    <span class="num text-emphasized">
    commits
    commits
```

I think the problem comes from the spaces. ?

Thank you

Comment: It should be `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[:digit:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '/<span class="num text-emphasized">/ {f=NR} f && f+1==NR {print $1}' file
3,200
```

or

```
awk '/<span class="num text-emphasized">/ {f=NR} f && f+1==NR {sub(/,/,"");print $1}' file
3200
```

When `<span class="num text-emphasized">` is found, print the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? (GNU awk for multi-char RS and 3rd arg to match()):

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' 'match($0,/.*<span\s+class="num\s+text-emphasized">\s*(\S+)\s*<\span>/,a){gsub(/,/,"",a[1]); print a[1]}' file
3200
```

The above will work no matter what white space is in and between lines.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got some HTML there. I'd recommend using an HTML parser:

```
$ perl -Mojo -E'$d=Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/; <> }); 
  say $d->at("span.num.text-emphasized")->text =~ s/,//r' file.html
3200
```

Slurp in the HTML file, construct a DOM object. Get the text content of the span you are interested in, removing the comma.